# Máxima data SQL

Tags: sql

Estou com a seguinte tabela `T_PGTOS_ADESAO`:

```
Adesão  | Tipo Adesão | Data Vencimento Boleto | Data Pgto Boleto 
12247   | Cartão      |    20-03-2018          | 03-03-2018
38497   | Boleto      |    15-05-2018          | 10-05-2018
48289   | Cartão      |    20-05-2018          | 02-01-1900 
89497   | Saque Compl.|    23-04-2018          | 02-01-1900
90849   | Boleto      |    15-05-2018          | 07-05-2018
```

Gostaria de criar uma coluna com a data máxima da Data Pgto Boleto (que, no exemplo dado é a data 10-05-2018) para todas as linhas, assim:

```
Adesão  | Tipo Adesão | Data Vencimento Boleto |Data Pgto Boleto| DT_UTLIMO_PGTO
12247   | Cartão      |    20-03-2018          | 03-03-2018     | 10-05-2018
38497   | Boleto      |    15-05-2018          | 10-05-2018     | 10-05-2018
48289   | Cartão      |    20-05-2018          | 02-01-1900     | 10-05-2018
89497   | Saque Compl.|    23-04-2018          | 02-01-1900     | 10-05-2018
90849   | Boleto      |    15-05-2018          | 07-05-2018     | 10-05-2018
```

porém quando faço a consulta

```
SELECT 
T_PGTOS_ADESAO.*,
MAX(Data Pgto Boleto) as DT_UTLIMO_PGTO
from T_PGTOS_ADESAO
GROUP BY 
Adesão
,[Tipo Adesão]
,[Data Vencimento Boleto]
,[Data Pgto Boleto]
```

ele retorna o valor da Data Vencimento Boleto para cada linha.

poderiam me ajudar, por gentileza?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Funções agregadoras como `MAX()` são aplicadas no contexto do `GROUP BY`, e como você está agrupando por todos os campos, o MAX() retornará a maior data limite de cada registro.

Experimente com um subselect:

```
SELECT 
  T_PGTOS_ADESAO.*,
  (select MAX(Data Pgto Boleto) from T_PGTOS_ADESAO) as DT_UTLIMO_PGTO
from T_PGTOS_ADESAO;
```

Assim, o MAX() é aplicado no contexto grupo implícito de todos os registros da tabela.

Comment: Muito obrigada! Vou tentar amanhã e aviso se deu certo =)